# Is it possible to implement a conditional attribute on a field in Odoo?

Tags: xml, attributes, conditional-statements, odoo-8, odoo

Does anyone know if it is possible to implement a conditional attribute on a field?

For example:

```
<field name="name"/>
```

And if condition is met:

```
<field name="name" string="Custom Name"/>
```

I tried this approach:

```
<field name="name" attrs="{'invisible': [('condition', '=', False)]}"/>
<field name="name" string="Custom Name" attrs="{'invisible': [('condition', '=', True)]}"/>
```

When condition changes, label also changes, but then the field stop working properly. I mean it only registers entered values for second field `name`. If I change condition to `False`, it does not show the value that was entered, like that would be new field, even though it is the same field, just one time it is with `string` attribute, other without it.

Answer (score 2):

You can only show each field in the form view once, as you found out. You only can use the following conditional attributes within the `attrs` attribute:

```
<field name="name" attrs="{'invisible': [('condition', '=', False)]}"/>
<field name="name2" attrs="{'readonly': [('condition', '=', False)]}"/>
<field name="name3" attrs="{'required': [('condition', '=', False)]}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add labels.

```
<div >
    <label for="name" attrs="{'invisible': [('condition','=',False)]}"/>
    <label for="name" string="Custom String" attrs="{'invisible': [('condition','=',True)]}"/>
</div>
<field name="name" nolabel="1" />
```

only problem is that it will not have a vertical separator between label and field value.

Answer (score 0):

If it is all about to update the label of the field based on condition then you should try fields_view_get.